# procedural animation

Tags: python, procedural-generation

I am trying to work out the best approach to have a physics-enabled animation within pygame.
After researching how it is implemented I have come to find myself much more confused than when I set off.
If possible could you point me in the direction of any resources on how this is implemented?

Comment: See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*